# Non-conformable arrays error in multiplication of maxtrix

Tags: r

I am extremely new to R and I'm trying to learn as much as I can from several sources. I am currently working on a problem that I have for class, which more than likely has a simple solution. However, when I go to multiply the matrices I have, I get a non-conformable arrays. Here are my matrices.

```
y1 <- c(2,4,7)  
y1 <- matrix(data= y1, nrow = 1, ncol=3)

y2 <- c(5,3,8)
y2 <- matrix(data= y2, nrow = 3, ncol=1)`
```

> y1%%y2
>       Error in y1%%y2 : non-conformable arrays

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you need `y1 %*% c(y2)`

Comment: @akrun That got rid of the non-conformity arrays, but why did you add a 'c' to the multiplication? What does that mean exactly?

Comment: It removes the dimenssions of the matrix and coerces to a `vector`

Comment: @akrun Does this mean that this should be used when multiplying all matrices that have non-conformity array errors without the 'c' , or just in this case? Just to clear one last thing up.

Comment: Sorry, your expression was not correct `y1 %*% y2`  ( I didn't notice it earlier)

Comment: @akrun Thank you so much! This fixed my problem completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because `%%` is a different function  whereas we need `%*%`

```
y1 %*% y2
```